# How do I change the name of my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

HI everyone!

i have application that uploded via other company(not my company)

i decided to upload the application via my comany so...

i can't upload my app on the same name as the company uploded alreday.

there is a way that the other company can delete the app from app store or rename

the application name, so i can upload the app via my comany as the same name?

thank!

Comment: Ask Apple, if the other company simply deletes the app or changes its name someone else could potentially claim it too, though that seems a slim chance.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like this should go through Apple support. They can probably transfer ownership behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the app name and app id, recompile the app with the new provisioning profile for that app id (bundle identifier) and then upload it through your company's developer program portal.

And then hope that apple doesn't reject the apps on the basis that an app with essentially the same code already exists.

Also, i hope you have no copyright problems with *the other company*.